# Simple way to make array of progressing series in Swift like 1,3,5,

Tags: arrays, swift

What is the best way to make array with progressing series just like

`1,3,5,.. till 99`

What modification needed in this code fr achiving this.

```
 let arrayAP = Array(1...99) // 1,2,..99
```

Comment: It is similar question, not exactly a duplicate problem. That question answer is as simple as `Array(0..10)`.

Comment: @adev That question also says *"with a certain step"*. Their example just happens to have a step of 1. The answer by Moritz covers the case where `step != 1` as well. Your answer is also contained in that answer, thus making the whole question a duplicate.

Comment: @Keiwan, There is no way someone searching for this question to find that question as a duplicate of this. Like that there could be tons of questions on SO which can be considered a variation of each other and some answer may have went beyond the question to answer all the variations. That doesn't make it duplicate for someone searching for an exact question like this.

Comment: @adev How is the question impossible to find if I managed to find it in about a minute? You could possibly have a point if this question was at least a variation of the other one, but it isn't - it's an exact duplicate. I would appreciate it if you could point out any difference you see between the two questions. Finally, if a question is a subset of another question and can be answered with a subset of the existing answers it should be closed as a duplicate based on SO standards.

Comment: @Keiwan, I disagree, the question asks to get solution for `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` with an interval which is `Array(0..10)`. In this case it wont work. I am not sure what is that confuses you. If I search for a duplicate for a question in SO, I am sure most of the time I can find some other variations too in a minute.

Comment: @adev Did you read my first comment? Let me quote the question again: The OP is looking to populate an array of integers **"(...) increasing with a certain step (...)"** The array given is just a *quote* **"example"** (In this case the example step is 1 but they explicitly state they want a solution for arbitrary steps). As far as my own question is concerned I already gave you an explanation over there why the "duplicate" makes no sense which you obviously also didn't read.

Comment: I am not interested in continuing this argument over this. Clearly this is not going in any constructive way. I have clearly showed you both cases with your own question and a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest is **(Swift 3)**:

```
let arrayAP = Array(stride(from: 1, to: 100, by: 2))
```

It can be done in many different ways. I prefer this approach since we are not creating an array and then filtering it again in this approach.

Comment: If you print this, you will get output as `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]`

Comment: As a cute little readability bonus, I like to do this: `stride(from: 1, to: 100, by: +2)`

Comment: True that makes it little bit more readable. But I have also noticed that it also changes Array's type to `Array<double>` if we use "+" in by field. If it is just now "2", it will be `Array<Int>`. That is what happening in my playground.

Comment: Interesting! I guess I've only ever used stride for working with doubles

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

I think this will help you...

```
let arrayAP = Array(0...99).filter { $0 % 2 == 1 }

print(arrayAP)
```

Comment: You can change this to `Array(0...99).filter { $0 % 2 == 1 }`. You can use `filter` instead of `flatMap`.

Comment: This is wasteful, as it does an unnecessary intermediate array allocation, and does an extra pass through the array

Comment: @adev yes this way is also simple.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @adev is nice and works well. Here is just another approach which might be useful in other cases.

For both **Swift 3 & 4**:

```
let arrayAP = Array(1...99).filter({$0 % 2 == 1})
```

**BONUS**

For filtering, the difference is *in Swift 4, `filter` is able to return a new object of the original type.* For example,

**Swift 3**

```
// Types of array1 and array1 must be Array
let array1: Array = Set(1...99).filter({$0 % 2 == 1}) // Will compile
let array2: Set = Set(1...99).filter({$0 % 2 == 1}) // Will fail
```

**Swift 4**

```
// Types of array1 and array2 are not necessary to be Array
let array1: Array = Set(1...99).filter({$0 % 2 == 1}) // Will compile
let array2: Set = Set(1...99).filter({$0 % 2 == 1}) // Will compile
```